# Nested Functions in C - Best Practices

Tags: c

I just realized a function may be defined inside another function in C:

```
void main(){
  int foo(){ return 2; };
  printf("%d\n", foo());
}
```

Besides being a neat trick, the useful thing about this is that the inner function is private to the outer function. But... is that a good enough reason to do this in a "real-world" application? What are the best practices for using this syntax?

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Someone who is using the *very* non-standard functions-within-functions is unlikely to give a damn about what main returns :-)

Comment: How many levels can we nest upto?

Comment: @Alok: Fair enough, but this is just a minimalist example that I compiled in gcc. Please feel free to edit as-needed...

Comment: @eSKay - No idea, and it would almost certainly be implementation-dependant. Sounds like a good excuse to write a program/script to generate test programs to find out :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nested functions are a non-standard extension, [implemented by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) (and maybe others that I don't know about).  Seeing as it does not follow a standard, best practices probably include **not** using it in code you intend to be portable.

If your ultimate goal is to have "private" functions in C, then you are better off using separate files and making the "private" functions static so that they won't be linked to other object files.

Comment: Note also that even gcc supports it for C only, not C++.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a compiler extension rather than part of the C spec itself

see: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.431470.11

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a compiler that translates Pascal (which allows nested procedures) into C and relies on GCC to turn the result into a binary, then this functionality is certainly useful.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, embedded functions have visibility to their parent functions' symbols.  In some circumstances, maybe this could be useful to avoid global variables (help with thread safety?)  As this feature is GCC specific, I would seek to avoid it unless I really needed it.

Comment: By "visibility" do you mean access? In that case, that would be quite specific and unlike other semantics.

Comment: Yes, the embedded functions have, as far as I can tell, the same scoping as any other block inside a function.  From that GCC link in a previous comment, "The nested function can access all the variables of the containing function that are visible at the point of its definition. This is called lexical scoping. For example, here we show a nested function which uses an inherited variable..."